# Google App Engine: How to get 10MB incoming email limit?

Tags: google-app-engine

As per the url https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/overview (all the way at the end) there are two limits for incoming email. 16K when administrator is recipient and 10MB for all incoming email. What configuration do I need to tweak so the anything@appid.appspotmail.com is not an administrator receipient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, only the outbound mail has that 16KB limit when *sending* to an administrator. Your inbound mail must be sent to an address string@appid.appspotmail.com (which you wouldn't be able to register as admin) therefore you can receive 10MB incoming mail and no 'setting tweaks' are required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am hitting the 16K limit in the go runtime env. Can anyone confirm if this is specific to go runtime ? Bug, maybe ?

Comment: Looks like temporary glitch! Its ok now. Your answer is correct.